# How to filter out outliers variables within each of my sample groups in R

Tags: r, arrays, tidyverse

I have a data with variables in rows and samples in columns. The samples and Biological replicates of several groups. each group vary in the replicate number. an example is the follwoing:

```
Varibale Ctrl_1 Ctrl_2 Ctrl_3  DrugA_1  DrugA_2 DrugA_3 DrugA_4  DrugB_1 DrugB_2 DrugB_3
ALa     22.6438 28.3892 20.8251 27.9565 23.574  30.9032 25.0484 27.5785 29.5881 26.0501
Arg     152.146 166.179 93.2656 138.99  105.766 124.013 99.5645 110.642 115.571 121.694
Asn     27.0758 42.4504 30.9472 42.2874 34.0379 34.8214 36.2872 36.1781 42.2911 42.4052
Asp     165.854 351.983 232.19  249.624 114.803 96.9021 120.799 136.907 141.833 246.973
Glu     72.3663 168.251 116.67  167.514 86.3407 90.9513 100.363 122.004 134.128 175.909
Gln     119.269 147.754 107.945 152.588 102.166 115.641 165.737 133.397 147.295 172.286
Met     6.69636 13.0122 7.23503 16.6089 7.63006 6.23411 6.87084 5.65021 9.35852 12.9221
```

I have over 200 variable in my table. some times a variable is measured very low in one sample and very high in another within the same group I would like to write a code in R that helps me filter out these variable. I tried to figure out a way based on IQR but I did not succeed.

Comment: For the example data above, could you show the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is that you want to remove values when they are outside the IQR for a given variable (i.e., row). You could do so with:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~Variable, ~Ctrl_1, ~Ctrl_2, ~Ctrl_3, ~DrugA_1, ~DrugA_2, ~DrugA_3, ~DrugA_4, ~DrugB_1, ~DrugB_2, ~DrugB_3,
  "ALa", 22.6438, 28.3892, 20.8251, 27.9565, 23.574 , 30.9032, 25.0484, 27.5785, 29.5881, 26.0501,
  "Arg", 152.146, 166.179, 93.2656, 138.99 , 105.766, 124.013, 99.5645, 110.642, 115.571, 121.694,
  "Asn", 27.0758, 42.4504, 30.9472, 42.2874, 34.0379, 34.8214, 36.2872, 36.1781, 42.2911, 42.4052,
  "Asp", 165.854, 351.983, 232.19 , 249.624, 114.803, 96.9021, 120.799, 136.907, 141.833, 246.973,
  "Glu", 72.3663, 168.251, 116.67 , 167.514, 86.3407, 90.9513, 100.363, 122.004, 134.128, 175.909,
  "Gln", 119.269, 147.754, 107.945, 152.588, 102.166, 115.641, 165.737, 133.397, 147.295, 172.286,
  "Met", 6.69636, 13.0122, 7.23503, 16.6089, 7.63006, 6.23411, 6.87084, 5.65021, 9.35852, 12.9221
  )

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(-Variable, ~ifelse(between(.x, 
                                           quantile(c_across(-Variable), .25),
                                           quantile(c_across(-Variable), .75)), .x, NA))) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 7 × 11
#>   Variable Ctrl_1 Ctrl_2 Ctrl_3 DrugA_1 DrugA_2 DrugA_3 DrugA_4 DrugB_1 DrugB_2
#>   <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 ALa         NA     NA   NA       28.0   NA       NA     25.0     27.6   NA   
#> 2 Arg         NA     NA   NA       NA     NA      124.    NA      111.   116.  
#> 3 Asn         NA     NA   NA       42.3   NA       34.8   36.3     36.2   NA   
#> 4 Asp        166.    NA  232.      NA     NA       NA     NA      137.   142.  
#> 5 Glu         NA     NA  117.      NA     NA       NA    100.     122.   134.  
#> 6 Gln        119.   148.  NA       NA     NA       NA     NA      133.   147.  
#> 7 Met         NA     NA    7.24    NA      7.63    NA      6.87    NA      9.36
#> # … with 1 more variable: DrugB_3 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. and Sorry if I was not clear enough.     My initial idea was that I see that my replicates vary a lot in regard to one variable and this variation is observed within groups. I was searching for a way to eliminate an entire row if it varies a lot between the replicate in one group. one idea that I had is to remove an entire row if the values of replicates within any group do not fall into the IQR  of the same group.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand, can you provide the output you're looking for?